Override all black elements to desired color natively
I am currently working on a project where all the black elements from the design have been shifted to a dark blue color.
Would it be possible to override all elements which have black as base color in CSS? (i.e. text tags, buttons, list item bullets etc.)
I do not want to use the following structure since it would apply to all the elements. Furthermore, there may be a lot of cases where it would be unnecessary to override a color that has been designated to be different than dark blue from start:
* {
  color: #003B4A;
}

I am looking for something like this, where black is overriden natively by a color of my choice:
#000000 = #003B4A


Nope, that's a find+replace. If this was a requirement you should have used something like CSS variables to define when and where a certain color is used, and then switch the definition to the other color. But you cannot tell a browser to read black and display, say, blue - that would be redefining constant colors!

Is using JavaScript acceptable in your use case?

@AHaworth I prefer CSS since I am sharing this casuistry among several projects, which have different technologies but have the same base stylesheets.

The most intuitive solution would be to find out what the dark blue color to be replaced is, search for all references of that one in the project and replace it with the color of your desire. But if you need to do it programmatically, for whatever reason, learning, exercise, or whatever, then you can do this:


function replaceAttributeValue(element, attribute, source, target) {
    if (window.getComputedStyle( element ,null).getPropertyValue(attribute) == source) {
        element.style[attribute] = target;
    }
    for (let child of element.children) {
        replaceAttributeValue(child, attribute, source, target);
    }
}

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    let darkblue = 'rgb(0, 0, 139)';
    replaceAttributeValue(document.body, 'color', darkblue, 'black');
});
.mypattern {
    color: darkblue;
}
<div>
    <span class="mypattern">abc</span>
    <div class="mypattern">
        <span>def</span>
        <span style="color:red;">ghi</span>
    </div>
</div>



Explanation:

replaceAttributeValue is responsible to recursively replace the value of an attribute with target if the attribute was source
we compute the value of attribute and if it equals to source, then we set its value to target
we loop the children of the current element and we call the same method for them too
we need to pass the rgb value for 'darkblue', because that's what propertyValue will yield for it

